# How to get some part of a GL_TEXTURE_2D and put it in another GL_TEXTURE_2D (glGetTexImage, glReadPixels, glGetTextureSubImage)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm working on a small 2D openGL 3+ graphic engine using glfw and glad. I am able to load and display textures from files, or from memory. Now I need to get some texture data back from the GPU into the CPU, cut a small part of that data, create a new smaller texture from that, upload it to the GPU and display it.

I found a solution which *works*, using `glGetTexImage`, but it is very slow. I found other solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070930/copying-a-single-layer-of-a-2d-texture-array-from-gpu-to-cpu/32072660#32072660) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140527/glreadpixels-vs-glgetteximage/38148494#38148494), but I am not able to make those work.

I have tried multiple things :

- First I tried with `glgetTextureSubImage` which seem to be designed exactly for what I'm looking for. It is said that I need either openGL context 4.5 or extension *GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image*. I've tried both with the same result (not working).
- Then I tried with `glReadPixels` from an FBO. The result is the same.

There is probably something I don't understand, but I can't figure it out... Here is an example that can display *texture*, but not *subTexture*. There is an `init` function which handles most things related to creating the display, and an `exit` function. I've included those so the example is almost complete (I've not included shader code or shader compiling code, it is very simple and works as intended), but the part we are actually interested in is in the `main` function. The `Texture` object is just a small wrapper that can store texture metadata.

I would expect that example to render some part of my original texture, but I only get a black screen.

// Edit after comment : @Rabbid76 pointed out that I could use `glCopyImageSubData` to copy directly from one texture to another. But my real situation implies some treatment on subTexture before reuploading it into GPU, so I can't use that.

init code :

```
// You can skip this one, it's here for completeness
#include <glad/glad.h>
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "resourcemanager.h"

static std::vector<float> vertices;
static std::vector<unsigned int> indices;
static unsigned int VAO;
static unsigned int VBO;
static unsigned int EBO;
static Shader shader;
static GLFWwindow *window;

static void error_callback(int error, const char *description) {
  std::cerr << "Error(" << error << "): " << description << std::endl;
}

void init() {
  glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

  if (!glfwInit())
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

  window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "subimage test", nullptr, nullptr);

  if (!window) {
    glfwTerminate();
    throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't create window.");
  }

  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
  if (!gladLoadGLLoader(reinterpret_cast<GLADloadproc>(glfwGetProcAddress))) {
    glfwTerminate();
    throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't initialize glad.");
  }
  if (!GLAD_GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image)
    throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't load openGL extension "
                             "GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image which is needed");

  glfwSwapInterval(1);

  // This works fine
  shader = ResourceManager::loadShader(
      "shaders/subimage.vs", "shaders/subimage.fs", nullptr, "subimage");

  vertices = {
      1.0f,  1.0f,  // top right
      1.0f,  1.0f,  // tex coord
      1.0f,  -1.0f, // bottom right
      1.0f,  0.0f,  // tex coord
      -1.0f, -1.0f, // bottom left
      0.0f,  0.0f,  // tex coord
      -1.0f, 1.0f,  // top left
      0.0f,  1.0f   // tex coord
  };

  indices = {
      0, 3, 1, // first triangle
      1, 3, 2  // second triangle
  };

  glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
  glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
  glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
  glBindVertexArray(VAO);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
               static_cast<GLsizeiptr>(sizeof(float) * vertices.size()),
               vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
               static_cast<GLsizeiptr>(sizeof(float) * indices.size()),
               indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), nullptr);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float),
                        reinterpret_cast<void *>((2 * sizeof(float))));
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
  glBindVertexArray(0);
}

[[noreturn]] void exit(void) {
  glfwDestroyWindow(window);
  glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
  glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
  glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
  ResourceManager::cleanup();
  glfwTerminate();
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

main function :

```
// This is where my actual problem is
int main(void) {
  init();

  // test.png is an image : 1280px x 720px, it can be displayed properly, see
  // render loop.
  Texture texture =
      ResourceManager::loadTexture("textures/test.png", true, "test");

  uint8_t *subTextureData = new uint8_t[static_cast<size_t>(160 * 90 * 4)];
  memset(subTextureData, 0xFF, 160 * 90 * 4); // should be all white

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id);

  //  Alternative A : use glGetTextureSubImage() to fill subTextureData
  glGetTextureSubImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 160, 90, 1, GL_RGBA,
                       GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 160 * 90 * 4, subTextureData);

  //  Alternative B : create an FBO, use glReadPixels() to fill subTextureData
  //  GLuint fboId = 0;
  //  glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
  //  glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
  //  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
  //  GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id, 0); glReadPixels(0, 0, 160, 90, GL_RGBA,
  //  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, subTextureData); glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,
  //  0);

  Texture subTexture;
  glGenTextures(1, &subTexture.id);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, subTexture.id);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 160, 90, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
               subTextureData);

  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glfwPollEvents();
    glUseProgram(shader.id);
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f); // clear color is grey
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    //  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id); // <= using that displays the
    //  whole texture.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, subTexture.id); // screen is black
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
  }

  exit();
}
```

Comment: If you want to copy image data from a texture to another texture, then you can use [`glCopyImageSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCopyImageSubData.xhtml)

Comment: Yes, you're right, but that doesn't appear in my question, in my real situation I have to apply modifications to subTexture before reuploading it to GPU. I will edit the question.

Comment: Do the modifications in a shader. Either use a [Compute Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader) (OpenGL 4.3) or attach the target texture to framebuffer and render to the frambuffer and do the modifications in the fragment shader.

Comment: I should definitively look into that, but it would force me to do the computation in GLSL ,which I'm not very comfortable with yet.

Comment: *"[..] but it is very slow."* - the shader will solve that. You don't have to download/upload the texture and the shader operates parallel.